# QED gauge invariance

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, propagator, gauge, ward-identity

On P & S page.297, in the second paragraph from bottom, the book discussed gauge invariance of Faddeev-Popov procedure, following
a QED example. Where the photon propagator is:
$$ \widetilde{D}_F^{\mu \nu}(k)=\frac{-i}{k^2+i \epsilon}\left(g^{\mu \nu}-(1-\xi) \frac{k^\mu k^\nu}{k^2}\right).\tag{9.58}$$
I am troubled for the book's following statement:

> Notice in eq.(9.58) that $\xi$ multiplies a term in the photon propagator proportional to $k^{\mu}k^{\nu}$. According to the Ward identity (7.68), this replacement in a Green's function of any photon propagator by $k^{\mu}k^{\nu}$ yields zero.

So why $k^{\mu}k^{\nu}$ yields zero?

Comment: Of course, $k^\mu k^\nu$ is not zero. But $k^\mu j_\mu(k)$, where $j_\mu(k)$ is the Fourier transform of a current, vanishes (see Ward identity).

Comment: @Hyperon Thank you very much for your comment! Could you please explain more about that's the specific form of $j_{\mu}(k)$? I am very new to this, but I know Ward identity.

Comment: As a simple illustrative example consider e.g. the tree graph of $e^+ e^- \to \mu^+ \mu^-$ with the photon propagator in the $R_\xi$ gauge. You obtain an invariant matrix element of the form $j_\mu \tilde{D}^{\mu \nu} J_\nu$, where $j_\mu$ is the electronic current and $J_\nu$ the muonic one in momentum (Fourier) space. Written in terms of spinors and $\gamma$ matrices you can easily check that $j_\mu k^\mu= J_\nu k^\nu=0$. Physically this is nothing else than current conservation: $\partial_\mu j^\mu (x)=0$ in $x$-space becomes $k_\mu j^\mu (k)=0$ in Fourier space.

Comment: @Hyperon Thank you very much! Now I understand it, I am really appreciate your help! By the way, it seems that QED Ward Identity has some relationship with current conservation!